# crop face from video and save as image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to crop a face everytime it appears in video but it does not seem to be creating the image file.

I have included an imshow line to see if there is an image being created from the bounding boxes and there is a face that gets cropped. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

import os



detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("smallvid.mp4")    

while(True):

    ret, img = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    count = 1 
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cropped = img[ y : y+h, x : x+w ]
        cv2.imwrite("cropped_face" + str(id) + ".png", cropped)
        count=count+1
        cv2.imshow(out_dir+str(count), cropped); # show an image of each face
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2) # create bounding box around face


    cv2.imshow('frame',img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

        break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crop just like this.

```
img[y:y+w, x:x+w]
```